# Formatting array element using regex

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I have an array which contains quite a lot of elements,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Title] => 16MK002
            [Supplier] => John Lewis 
            //other data
        )
    //other elements        
)
```

My aim is to loop through all the array elements and check all Title's.  A title should be in the format YYSSSCCC where YY is the year, SSS is the first 3 letters of the Supplier, and CCC is the count.  So the above should be 16JOH001 while the next one with the same supplier will be 16JOH002.  In most cases this format is already being followed, but like the example above, sometimes it is not.  If the format is already correct, there is no need to touch it or reset the count.

So, to get to where I need to be, I have started like this

```
foreach($csvArray as $k => $row) {
    foreach($row as $key => $value) {
        if($csvArray[$k]['Title']) {
            print_r($csvArray[$k]['Title']);
        }
    }
}
```

Where I am confused is how I am going to check this against what I need it to be?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please either hover on the regex tag and click info, or click on the regex tag and click more info. You'll get to a page full of information on how you can write some test data and try some regular expressions on it. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info, give this tool a try: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/php/index.html

Answer (score 1):

How about not using a regex? Like:

```
if (strlen($csvArray[$k]['Title']) == 8) {
  $Y2K = substr($csvArray[$k]['Title'],0,2);
  $sup = substr($csvArray[$k]['Title'],2,3);
  $cnt = substr($csvArray[$k]['Title'],5,3);
  if (strtoupper($sup) != strtoupper(substr($csvArray[$k]['Supplier'],0,3))) {
    # doing something about this
  }
} else {
  # doing something else about this
}
```

Otherwise you're going to want to use something like this: `(\d{2})([A-Z]{3})(\d{3})`. Try pressing the [PHP Button on this page](http://fiddle.re/gwtu0a).